# will redux updates the value everywhere or just stores the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Will redux updates the value everywhere
like: var [a, setA] = useState(0) in react app
or just stores the data like var a = 0;
And is better to learn 'redux' or 'easy-peasy'
sorry for my english, its bad
..

Comment: You can listen to store changes with ``store.subscribe`` and update your variables there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Redux (more, the react-redux library) is propagating your data into all components and rerendering those once required data changes.

The official recommendation of the Redux team is to learn Redux Toolkit, not Easy-Peasy or one of the thousands of other helper libraries built on top of Redux - as that way you will know the "standard way" of doing things and not one special solution that has relatively few users. (Easy peasy has less than 5% of the RTK userbase.)

Best way of getting started with that is the official "Essentials" tutorial: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Ok            But will update everywhere like useState

Comment: `useState` will not update everywhere, but only one component since it is local component state.
React-redux' `useSelector` *will* update all components relying on a piece of state.